# can mysql handle searches with multiple varying columns?

Tags: mysql, search

I have a search interface with multiple search fields (about 10)

```
order count (min, max)
order value (min, max)
order date (min, max)
followers (min, max)
facebook (min, max)
instagram (min, max)
twitter (min, max)
youtube (min, max)
linkedin (min, max)
```

Users can enter values for any combination of the filters. e.g.

```
order count min: 10, order date max: 2020-05-01, followers min: 10000
```

Is this a use case that mysql can cover? (I am concerned that this requires separate indexes for every possible combination of filters)
Do I need to use specialized solutions for this kind of queries? (e.g. elasticsearch, algolia, etc.)

I have already tried to have all the data in one table with separate columns for each value and I have also saved the filter values in a separate table:

```
filter_values_integers
id, object_id, filter, value
1, 1, followers, 9999
2, 1, instagram, 555
3, 2, followers, 2893
...
```

The first variant (separate columns) would require many indexes and the second relies on joins.
Unfortunately both attempts have very poor performance.

I'd be grateful if someone could point me into the right direction.

Comment: These points see to have been picked up before in comments to your previous questions, but maybe with repetition the message will get through: [Why should I provide an MCRE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Strawberry I don't think it is necessary to reproduce my setup. It is rather a general question whether I am using the right tool for the job in the first place or not.

Comment: Maybe Elastisearch